# What wrong the function agregate SELECT AVG (uh1, uh2, uh3, uh4, uh5) AS ruh FROM nilai

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT AVG(uh1,uh2,uh3,uh4,uh5) AS ruh  FROM nilai;
```

What wrong function aggregate

My table;
[image]

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uh2,uh3,uh4,uh5) as RUH FROM nilai LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: what's the error showing?

Comment: @Affan Media please post a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

In your case, the sql statement to create a table  with only the needed fields, the select statement (which you already have) and the error you got when executed the statement.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uh2,uh3,uh4,uh5) as RUH FROM nilai LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: That's not how AVG() works. It averages *columns*, not *rows*. If you want the average of a row, you would do it yourself. `SELECT (uh1 + uh2 + uh3 + uh4 + uh5) / 5 as uhAverage FROM ...` If you actually want to aggregate the average all five of the columns for all rows, then `SELECT AVG(uh1 + uh2 + uh3 + uh4 + uh5)` instead and add a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're looking for but the [`AVG()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) expects a single argument (and, in MySQL 8, an optional window function):

```
AVG([DISTINCT] expr) [over_clause]
```

Perhaps you don't want an aggregate function at all and just want to calculate the average of those five *columns* rather than *rows*:

```
SELECT id_nilai, (uh1 + uh2 + uh3 + uh4 + uh5) / 5 AS ruh
FROM nilai;
```